# Passing zero to function that takes pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Assume that the constructor for a class Car has this signature

```
Car(Something* b[])
```

Will the statement

```
 Car a(0);
```

call this constructor as well, or does the parameter have to be a pointer like

```
Car a(new Something[5]);
```

Also should I use reference Something& b[] instead of pointer if I intend to use new statement like above example?

Comment: `new Something[5]` will give the type `Something*`, while the function expects `Something**`.

Comment: @interjay Why does the function expect pointer to a pointer? If I intend to use `new Something[5]` should the signature only be `Something b[]`

Comment: Yes, the signature should be `Something *b` or `Something b[]` (these are the same thing in a function parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, passing zero to a function that takes pointer as parameter will work.

```
Car a(0);
```

will properly call `Car`'s constructor with a null pointer although if your constructor doesn't check for null pointers, you're going to run into problems.

```
Car a(new Something[5]);
```

will not.  You declared `Car`'s constructor to accept `Something**` by using both `*` and `[]` in `Car(Something* b[])`.  Unless you wanted a pointer to a pointer, you can change the declaration to either `Car(Something* b)` or `Car(Something b[])`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass `0`: it can be used as a *null pointer constant* anywhere that an object pointer is expected. You might prefer to write `nullptr` (in modern C++) or `NULL` (if you're stuck in a pre-2011 world), to make it slightly clearer that that's the intention.

Of course, if the constructor doesn't check whether the argument is null, then you'll get nasty runtime errors.

Note that the function actually expects a pointer to a pointer (or to the first of an array of pointers), not a pointer to an object, so `new Something[5]` (a pointer to the first of an array of `Something`) is not a valid argument. Confusingly, you can declare a pointer argument as if it were an array, so `T b[]` is equivalent to `T * b`, and `Something* b[]` is equivalent to `Something ** b`. In order to pass a pointer to a `Something` (or to the first of an array of `Something`), change the declaration to either `Something*` or `Something[]`.

Comment: Is this any different from passing by reference in this case? Does passing `Something a[]` the same as passing reference?

Comment: @user3751232: It's the same as passing a pointer, which is similar but not quite the same as passing a reference. Your introductory book should describe pointers and references in detail.